# Symfony2 Bulk Delete with QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to do a query for bulk deleting, but apparently it doesn't do the JOIN actions. Any thoughts?

```
$queryBuilder = $em
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->delete('Bundle:ClassA', 'a')
                ->join('a.classB', 'b')
                ->where('b = :parent')
                ->setParameter('parent', $parent);

      $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

This returns:

> "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 38 near 'b = :parent AND':
>   Error: 'b' is not defined."

Answer (score 4):

DQL does not support joins in DELETE and UPDATEs, even if the underlaying database, like MySQL, supports it.

This is the quickiest workaround:

```
$results = $em
    ->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('Bundle:ClassA', 'a')
    ->join('a.classB', 'b')
    ->where('b = :parent')
    ->setParameter('parent', $parent)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

foreach ($results as $result){
    $em->remove($result);
}

$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
$queryBuilder = $em
                ->createQueryBuilder()
                ->delete('Bundle:ClassA', 'a')
                ->innerJoin('a.classB', 'b')
                ->where($qb->expr()->eq('b', ':parent'))
                ->setParameter(':parent', $parent);

      $queryBuilder->getQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer mansoulx, I tried it but all I'm getting is a blank page (the server goes down and I have to restart Apache to get it up again). Any thoughts?

Comment: is your `ClassA` entity linked with `ClassB` entity ? have you tried again and got an error ? i don't know why you got a blank page (may be you exit the code somewhere) !

Comment: Yes, with a ManyToOne relation, being ClassB ClassA's parent. I agree, is very strange. Is going down on "->where($qb->expr()->eq('b', ':parent'))", if I comment that line it throws the expected error on the next one.

Comment: $qb is used in where-clause but never defined. Use $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();$qb->delete()...